# Display Components child one by one in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, settimeout

this is my code:

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react'
            import uuid from 'uuid'

            import styles from './table.css'
            import Element from '../Element'

            class Table extends Component {

                constructor(props) {
                    super(props)

                    this.state = {
                        displayedElements: [],
                        nums: Array.from(Array(118).keys()).map(x => ++x)
                    }

                }

                handleDisplayElements() {

                    console.log('hola')
                    let nums = this.state.nums
                    let randNum = nums[Math.floor(Math.random() * nums.length)]

                    if(nums.length > 0) {
                        this.props.elements.map( el => {

                            if(nums[randNum] === el.number) {
                                let newElement = {
                                    id: uuid.v4(),
                                    number: el.number,
                                    symbol: el.symbol,
                                    name: el.name,
                                    period: el.ypos,
                                    family: el.xpos,
                                    category: el.category
                                }
                                this.setState({
                                    displayedElements: this.state.displayedElements.concat(newElement),
                                    nums: this.state.nums.splice(randNum)
                                })
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }

                render() {
                    return(
                        <div className = {styles.table}>

                            { this.state.displayedElements.map( el => {
                                return(

                                    <Element
                                        id = {uuid.v4()}
                                        number = {el.number}
                                        symbol = {el.symbol}
                                        name = {el.name}
                                        category = {el.category}
                                        period = {el.period}
                                        family = {el.family}
                                    />
                                )

                                })

                            }

                            { this.handleDisplayElements() }

                        </div>
                    )
                }
            }

            export default Table
```

I would like to display Element randomly and one by one (because I would like to add a setTimeout afterwards). I just get to display one element if I setState "nums" in "handleDisplayElements" function. And I also get a warning

> Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within
>   `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be
>   a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an
>   anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.

I would like to know where to place this setState and how to make a loop to display all the child components (Element).

If you could let me know where to write the setTimeout to the Elements don`t appear all of sudden, I would thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> If you could let me know where to write the setTimeout to the Elements don`t appear all of sudden, I would thank you a lot!

I can think three options to solve this:

1. At `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` you should register a `setTimeout` that increases the state of the component by adding one element to displayedElements.
2. The parent of that element registers a loop (using `setInterval` for instance) that changes the `props` of that component adding the element one by one.
3. You set the inner elements to hidden and you pass them a delay (every element would have a different delay). After the delay, you remove the hidden property.